# VPN on demand: if VPN server is not reachable the entire device network connection is cut off from public internet

Tags: ios, vpn

I have a configuration profile for VPN on demand if the VPN server is down then internet is not getting connected.

I have enabled on demand VPN connection using below lines in my mobileconfig profile

```
<key>OnDemandEnabled</key>
<integer>1</integer>
<key>OnDemandMatchDomainsAlways</key>
<array>
    <string>*</string>                        
</array>
<key>OnDemandMatchDomainsNever</key>
<array/>
<key>OnDemandMatchDomainsOnRetry</key>
<array/>
<key>OnDemandRules</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Action</key>
        <string>Connect</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

On-Demand VPN is establishing as expected in iOS 6 & 7. Whereas when the VPN server is down, on-demand still tries to establish connection and it fails, hence the user is not able to reach the internet. I want to disable VPN connection when the VPN server is down, hence user can use the internet. I tried the following On-Demand rule to connect VPN when I able to reach a service of my VPN server else disconnect VPN.

### Approach 1:

```
<key>OnDemandRules</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>URLStringProbe</key>
        <string>http://myserverip/openvpn/server</string>
        <key>Action</key>
        <string>Connect</string>
    </dict>
 </array>
```

### Approach 2

```
 <key>OnDemandRules</key>
<array>
<dict>
   <key>RequiredURLStringProbe</key>                           
   <string>https://host.domain.com/nonexistent_url</string>                    
   <key>DomainAction</key>
   <string>ConnectIfNeeded</string>
 </dict>
 </array>
```

I tried both the approaches they neither connect the VPN nor Disconnect the VPN

I referred the following links

- http://www.derman.com/blogs/Example-iOS-VPN-OnDemand-Rules.
- http://jelockwood.blogspot.in/2014/03/how-to-do-vpn-on-demand-for-ios-at-zero.html
- [apple key reference document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef.pdf)

**Steps to Reproduce:**

- Configure you device VPN connection using OpenVPN client app with OpenVPN
  server(Certificate based authentication)
- Make sure you have a working VPN connection using OpenVPN server
- Configure a VPN on demand for any internet connection using wild card filter(*)
- Now shut your OpenVPN server down thats it.the internet connection of device will go down

**Expected Results:**

if OpenVPN server is not reachable then the device should not try to reach it again and again Instead after sometime it should stop trying and connect with public internet

**Actual Results:**

Device's internet connection is cut off

**Version:**
I tried in both iOS 6 and 7

I want to disable VPN or On-Demand feature in iOS 6 & 7 when VPN server is down.

Here is a [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-yFxDqROZVpbVltUXkxU1lkeEE/edit?usp=sharing) that has configuration profile(dummy) of mine.

Here is a [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-yFxDqROZVpdVRORWtqN2Ziblk/edit) that has ipcu console log when connection fails

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: I couldn't find any solution for this